# Echo data with eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to get data out of my table, and send that array of output over to my view and there echo out specific parts of it.

I get an exception error: Undefined index bassengId.

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bassengweb</title>

</head>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($htt))
{
    echo $htt['malingsId'];
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showIndex');

Route::post('/data', 'HomeController@showInput');
```

homecontroller.php

```
public function showIndex()
{
    return View::make('index');
}

    public function showInput()
{       
    $htt = hvertredjetime::all();
    return View::make('index')->with('htt', $htt);
}
```

If I try to just echo the $htt variable from index, I get:

```
[{"malingsId":1,"dato":"25.02.2014","tid":"12:44:00","frittKlor":"4.00","bundetKlor":"5.00","totalKlor":"9.00","ph":"7.00","autoPh":"8.00","autoKlor":"9.00","redox":"5.00","bassengId":1}]
```

I am a little stuck here, being new to this and not really seeing what I do wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `::all()` method you are returning an array

```
public function showInput()
{       
    $htt = hvertredjetime::all();
    return View::make('index')->with('htt', $htt);
}
```

In the View

```
@if(! is_null($htt))

@foreach($htt as $item)
     <p>{{ $item->bassengId }}</p>
@endforeach

@endif
```

Comment: This fixed it, thank you good sir, and thanks to everyone else that also helped!

Seems it did not want to echo it or even recognize it as an assoc array without the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access data like this, you should do:

```
return View::make('index')->with(array('htt' => $htt));
```

Instead, return it like this:

```
return View::make('index')->with($htt);
```

And then, in view, access it directly:

```
{{ bassengId }}
```

Comment: I now realize I forgot to add a line in homecontroller in the OP: $htt = hvertredjetime::all();, I shall edit that.

Comment: Okay, so I tested that out with the first line my echo disappears completely, although no error.

When I try the last line I get an illegal offset type error.

Comment: Can you also post the form that you're using ? The route you defined is using the showInput action with POST method... You should also try to output the array of htt with print_r($htt) to see how exactly this var looks. print_r($htt) instead of echo $htt['somename']

Comment: I've noticed also, that your returned data is json formatted, not a PHP array - how do you get your data ?

Comment: Hey thanks, didn't have a chance to read this until now. I tested print_r and the output was https://www.dropbox.com/s/ot35rwil38ov7it/hjelp2.png

I am not using a form to get the data out, I am fetching a single row from a table in my database.

Comment: With all() you're fetching all records. You should use the construct: $htt = hvertredjetime::first()->toArray(); return View::make('index')->with('htt', $htt); Then see what's the print_r() output. If it is an array of values, you'll be able to access them with the given field name.

Answer (score 0):

You should access to the variable like this :

```
if(isset($htt))
{
    echo $htt->bassengId;
}
```

or if you're using blade template :

```
@if(isset($htt))
    {{ $htt->bassengId }}
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I tried that I got an exception error that said:

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$bassengId

There must be something I'm missing..?

Also noticed I had a typo in the OP $htt['bassengId'] should've been $htt['malingsId'] as it's called in the table, edited that now.